# Web API HTTP methods best practice

Tags: javascript, api, rest, http, uri

I've been working on a personal Web project so far this summer which involves a back-end API.

With HTML not supporting the HTTP methods PUT or DELETE, but most REST API guidelines suggesting the use of PUT and DELETE, I was wondering where that leaves me in terms of designing my project.

In my eyes I have two options:

1. Use JavaScript AJAX on the front-end for sending any PUT and DELETE requests to an API which supports these methods
2. Use HTML POST requests as a proxy for POST/DELETE requests, and specify verbs within the request URI themselves e.g. POST to example.com/item/1/delete would delete item 1

I'm leaning towards option 1 but was wondering what is done in practice, or what other peoples personal preference is.

Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, I'd say this is dealer's choice.  I'd personally prefer the 2nd method but that's just me.  If you go for the 1st option then I'd recommend creating a class that has GET, POST, PUT, DELETE functions, wrapping a common ancestor that handles the call and returns a promise (or similar AJAX object).  Really, this isn't something to be overly concerned about.

Comment: Personally, i would go with AJAX for PUT & DELETE. Because it gives you control over the execution. The errors are meaningful. By seeing the error you will be able to identity what is the error as the error codes are specific to that `VERB`.  In your 2nd approach you need to handle everything on your own. As all requests are `POST` the error response codes will be same and it's difficult to troubleshoot. So i strongly recommend going with `Ajax` or `Fetch` for making HTTP requests.